# Android root symbol resize

Tags: javascript, java, android, math

How do i make square root to dynamically resize depending whats inside the root ? (example picture)

[image]

I need an idea, new to this level of programming. I only heard it's hard and time consuming, but not solutions. Only idea that comes to my mind is to make a custom ViewGroup, and still don't know how to do that.
I am making a calculator app. Thank u.
EDIT: Building app in android studio.

Comment: That appears to be TeX/LaTeX. You could try [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/). That's what [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and many other stack exchange sites use.

Comment: You can accomplish this by defining your root symbol as 9-patch drawable that has ever-growing tail.

Comment: I cant uptove both comments, weird ... @ror when i do that, how can i on button click add that image/view to edittext at certain position ? should i use something else ?